# jquery detach and load need to fade In and Out

Tags: jquery, fading, detach

I'm trying to make this function work nicer but I'm having problem to find a solution.

**I want to make the pages fading in and out to each other. 
any suggestion?**

```
        $('.edit-account').click(function(){

            $('#section-wrapper').detach();

            $('#inline-cont').load('../my-profile/edit-profile.html #inline_content');

            $('#inner-wrap').load('../my-profile/edit-profile.html #section-wrapper', function(){
                $('#close-account').click(function() {
                        $('#section-wrapper').detach();
                        $('#inline-cont').load('../my-profile/close-account.html #inline_content');
                        $('#inner-wrap').load('../my-profile/close-account.html #section-wrapper');
                });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options here, hard to tell what the best solution would be for you without more context / CSS / HTML.

1. Animate with jQuery (assumes you have the CSS property opacity set to 0 initially)

   $('#yourSelector').animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, function() {// Animation complete.});

More about .animate here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

1. Use CSS Transitions (no support on IE <10 http://caniuse.com/#search=transition)
   If you initially have your opacity set to 0, then just change the element's CSS opacity property to 1 `$('#yourSelector').css('opacity':'1');`
   after it's loading in the DOM and CSS transitions will take care of the rest.

   .yourSelector {
   -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in 0s;
   -moz-transition: opacity .2s ease-in 0s;
   -o-transition: opacity .2s ease-in 0s;
   -ms-transition:opacity .2s ease-in 0s;
   transition:opacity .2s ease-in 0s;
   }